# How can I create a multiple-select lookup field in CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am trying to create a new custom look-up field listing all the products. I would like to be able to select more than one value in the product list for a particular customer. This should also enable reports to pick up the values selected.

Right now, I have checkbox field that does not allow for reporting.

I am looking for something similar to selecting multiple resources while creating service activities.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you look at creating many to many relationships? You can place the grids on the form so they appear in line, that will allow you to easily have multiple select functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would be please be able to explain more? I am a newbie here!

Answer (score 0):

That function allow you to get "Multi" lookup for "product" entity:

```js
MultiLookup = function (_serverUrl) {
    var args = new Object();
    args.items = new Array();
    var url = _serverUrl + "/_controls/lookup/lookupinfo.aspx?LookupStyle=multi&class=alllookups&objecttypes=1024&DefaultViewId=%7bA066D18A-8A4A-44EE-B78E-9A870DC799DD%7d&DisableViewPicker=1&browse=0&ShowNewButton=1&ShowPropButton=1";
    var dialogParam = 'dialogWidth:800px;dialogHeight:600px;dialogLeft=0px;dialogTop=0px;help:0;status:1;scroll:0;center:1;resizable:yes;'
    var lItems = window.showModalDialog(url, args, dialogParam);

    if ((lItems != null) && (lItems.items != null) && (lItems.items.length > 0))
        return lItems.items;
    else {
        // rollup 12 -->
        lItems = JSON.parse(lItems);
        if ((lItems != null) && (lItems.items != null) && (lItems.items.length > 0)) {
            return lItems.items;
        } // rollup 12 -->
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can change "objecttypes" to get other entities.